# VB.Net OLEDB ExecuteNonQuery INSERT INTO - No effect on Database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledbcommand

Here is my issue:
I have the code below. 
If I debug my code and copy the queries directly into MS Access the Queries work perfectly fine but if I execute it from my application no change are made to the table.

Note that the connection to the DB is OK as I am doing several Select before that are working perfectly well.

I am probably making something stupid but it is so big I cannot see it after many hours working on it.

I know I should use parameters in my query and I did originally but I change it within my many try to make it work and I suppose this should not change much anyway.

```
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim sQuery As String = String.Empty

    Try
        cmd.CommandText = "DELETE * FROM tbl_Invoices"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("PrepareInvoicing Delete" & vbCrLf & ErrorToString())
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    'Insert into the Invoice table the fleet info with Usage for the invoicing period selected
    Try
        sQuery = String.Empty
        sQuery = sQuery & "INSERT INTO tbl_Invoices "
        sQuery = sQuery & "SELECT tbl_Fleet.CustomerName AS CustomerName, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.CountryCode AS CountryCode, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "#" & DateSerial(InvoicingYear, InvoicingMonth + 1, 0) & "# AS InvoiceDate, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.Area AS Area, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.Group AS [Group], "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.Site_nm AS SiteName, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Sites.RCS AS CustomerPO, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.Site_Addr_1 AS SiteAddress1, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.Site_Addr_2 AS SiteAddress2, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.Site_Addr_ZIP AS ZIP, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.Site_Addr_cty AS City, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.model_nm AS ProductDescription, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.product_no AS ProductNumber, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.serial_no AS SerialNumber, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.hostname AS hostname, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.asset_no AS AssetNumber, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.Grid AS Grid, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.ChangeOrderID AS ChangeOrderID, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Fleet.install_date AS InstalledDate, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "INT(((tbl_Fleet.install_date - temptbl_CO.ChangeOrderStartDate)/365.25)+1) AS YearInContract, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "(tbl_RM.BlackClicks + tbl_RM.AccentClicks) AS BlackPages, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "(tbl_RM.ColorClicks + tbl_RM.ProfessionalColorClicks) AS ColorPages "
        sQuery = sQuery & "FROM tbl_Fleet, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_Sites, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "tbl_RM, "
        sQuery = sQuery & "(SELECT DISTINCT tbl_Bases.ProductNumber, tbl_Bases.ChangeOrderID, tbl_Bases.ChangeOrderStartDate FROM tbl_Bases WHERE tbl_Bases.CustomerName = '" & mdlGlobalStuff.SelectedCustomerName & "' AND tbl_Bases.CountryCode = '" & mdlGlobalStuff.SelectedCountryCode & "')  AS temptbl_CO "
        sQuery = sQuery & "WHERE tbl_Fleet.CustomerName = '" & mdlGlobalStuff.SelectedCustomerName & "' "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Fleet.CountryCode = '" & mdlGlobalStuff.SelectedCountryCode & "' "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Fleet.LoadDate = #" & LoadFleetDate & "# "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND MONTH(tbl_RM.RMDate) = " & Month(LoadUsageDate) & " "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND YEAR(tbl_RM.RMDate) = " & Year(LoadUsageDate) & " "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Fleet.CustomerName = tbl_Sites.CustomerName "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Fleet.CountryCode = tbl_Sites.CountryCode "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Fleet.Site_nm = tbl_Sites.Site_nm "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Fleet.CustomerName = tbl_RM.CustomerName "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Fleet.CountryCode = tbl_RM.CountryCode  "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Fleet.serial_no = tbl_RM.SerialNumber "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Fleet.product_no = temptbl_CO.ProductNumber "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Fleet.ChangeOrderID = temptbl_CO.ChangeOrderID "
        cmd.CommandText = sQuery
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Step 1")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("PrepareInvoicing: Invoicing step 1" & vbCrLf & ErrorToString())
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    'Update the "non aging" Bases (if Base.contractYear = 0) in the Invoice table
    Try
        sQuery = String.Empty
        sQuery = sQuery & "UPDATE tbl_Invoices "
        sQuery = sQuery & "INNER JOIN tbl_Bases ON tbl_Bases.ProductNumber  =  tbl_Invoices.ProductNumber "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Bases.ChangeOrderID = tbl_Invoices.ChangeOrderID "
        sQuery = sQuery & "SET tbl_Invoices.Base = tbl_Bases.BasePrice "
        sQuery = sQuery & "WHERE tbl_Bases.CustomerName = '" & mdlGlobalStuff.SelectedCustomerName & "' "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Bases.CountryCode = '" & mdlGlobalStuff.SelectedCountryCode & "' "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Bases.ContractYear = 0 "
        cmd.CommandText = sQuery
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Step 2")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("PrepareInvoicing: Invoicing step 2" & vbCrLf & ErrorToString())
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    'Update the "aging" Bases (if Base.contractYear <> 0) in the Invoice table
    Try
        sQuery = String.Empty
        sQuery = sQuery & "UPDATE tbl_Invoices "
        sQuery = sQuery & "INNER JOIN tbl_Bases ON tbl_Bases.ProductNumber  =  tbl_Invoices.ProductNumber "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Bases.ChangeOrderID = tbl_Invoices.ChangeOrderID "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Bases.ContractYear =  tbl_Invoices.YearInContract  "
        sQuery = sQuery & "SET tbl_Invoices.Base = tbl_Bases.BasePrice "
        sQuery = sQuery & "WHERE tbl_Bases.CustomerName = '" & mdlGlobalStuff.SelectedCustomerName & "' "
        sQuery = sQuery & "AND tbl_Bases.CountryCode = '" & mdlGlobalStuff.SelectedCountryCode & "' "
        cmd.CommandText = sQuery
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Done")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("PrepareInvoicing: Invoicing step 3" & vbCrLf & ErrorToString())
        Exit Sub
    End Try
```

Comment: Are you sure about the connection string stuff? These symptoms are a strong clue that something is bad there and in the configuration of your project files. Could you post the connectionstring? (Of course the Sql Injection and the parsing problems come next)

Comment: As a starter, can you try something simple to insert into your table ? That way you know if it's a connection problem or a query syntax problem... Also ExecuteNonQuery() returns an integer indicating how many rows were affected, try to display this value as well...

Comment: When you call `ExecuteNonQuery` there are only three possible results.  It can throw an exception, in which case something went wrong; it can return zero, in which case there were no changes to save; it can return a non-zero value, in which case there were changes to save and they were saved.  Which is it in your case?  More often that not it is option 3, which means that everything is working as it should and the person is simply looking in the wrong place and/or at the wrong time for data.  If that the case for you, I can provide an appropriate answer that involves setting a single property.

Comment: By the way, amongst other things, you should learn to use XML literals, which would mean that you could avoid all that ugly and error-prone string concatenation to build SQL code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. my issue is not solved yet at least I am making some progress.

Comment: iniPath = Application.StartupPath
'Initial test of local DB the connection
sConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                      "Data Source=" & iniPath & "\InvoicingToolDB.accdb;" & _
                      "Persist Security Info=False;"

In my Visual studio env I have put the DB in the Project folder (WindowsApplication1/WindowsApplication1)

Thank for your help all.

Comment: You don't need to specify the data file path explicitly.  Use "Data Source=|DataDirectory|\InvoicingToolDB.accdb" and the system will resolve the actual path at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and post this as an answer because, based on my experience, it's at least 95% likely to be applicable.

When you add a local data file, e.g. MDB or ACCDB file, to your project, it gets copied to the project folder along with all the other source files.  That file is part of your project, not part of your application.  Any schema changes or default data gets added to that file but it does NOT get touched at run time while testing.

When you build your project, that source file gets copied to the output folder along with your EXE.  It's that copy that your application works with at run time.  Any data you save gets saved to that working copy, NOT the source file.

By default, a new copy of the source file is made and the working copy overwritten every time you build.  That means that, if you run your app in the debugger, save some data, stop the app, make a code change and then run the app again, the data you saved will disappear.

So, the mistake that you're probably making, like so many, is that you're either looking in the source file for the data you saved at run time or you're looking in the working copy after it has been overwritten by the next build.  The solution to this "issue" is simple.  Select your data file in the Solution Explorer, open the Properties window and set the `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy if Newer`.  That means that when you build, the working copy will only ever be overwritten if the source file is newer, which will be the case if you've modified the schema or edited the default data.  If you ever need to refresh your working database you simply delete it manually from the output folder or temporarily set the `Copy to Output Directory` back to `Copy Always`.

You may wonder why they use multiple files in the first place but it's perfectly logical and actually a very good thing.  If you only had one file and you used it for testing then what happens when it comes time to deploy?  You'd have to waste time cleaning up that one file and then you might miss something anyway.  This way, you just keep on using your Debug copy for testing and you'll always get a nice clean data file when you do a Release build.

Comment: Thanks A LOT!! :-) this is it. I just feel stupid but everything is working now.